# Library JAR with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm working on a project with multiple subprojects and they all use a utilities library that I created for hashing, signing and encrypting messages. This library is basically a wrapper for bouncy castle.

When I run the tests associated with the library, everything passes and it's alright. When I package the utilities library into the jar two things happen:

1. The subproject that is using the library cannot find the jars associated with bouncy castle.
2. Even when I add the bouncy castle jars to the subproject that is using the library, the project cannot find the bouncy castle security provider "BC"

Here's the configuration of the exported utilities jar in intellij:
[image: Artifact Picture]

The error:
[image: error]

Security provider initialization:
 [image: initialization]

Why can't I export a library with an included security provider? Is this a side effect from the generated class loader?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you only mentioned [tag:bouncycastle] with 67 followers (most of which will be inactive). Always try and include a "higher up" tag such as [tag:cryptography] to get your question noticed (between the ten million questions out there).

Comment: Thanks added the new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providers need to be signed. It could be that you're messing with the verification routine, although this is hard to tell from a distance. If you are repackaging the BC provider you're certainly in trouble though, and using a different class loader may very well mess with the provider signature as well, yes.

Another issue may be that you register the provider in a constructor. If the constructor is not called before the provider then you may run into issues. Generally you should register the provider at the earliest convenience, i.e. in a static code block of the first class that is used for your application. Note that there is no risk in registering a provider multiple times - it will just find that one has already registered under the same name and do nothing.

Comment: What is interesting is the Crypto class is a lazily initialized singleton. When I decompiled the Crypto class with the provider in a static block it looked the same as when I had it in the constructor (this might be intellij doing the static class holder pattern optimization under the covers). I do initialize the class before it is used though. So I'm gonna take a look at how to repackage the BC provider. I thought it should work like any other jar since I have it in my classpath for the subprojects.

Comment: Still having issues packaging the BC jar with my utilities jar but I guess I can expect my subprojects to provide it.